# Having trouble with select function. Keeps adding in columns I want to not have in data frame

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a long data frame that looks like this

```
 Site Grid Trap.Number      Lat      Long        x       y
1    PAT   A1           1 37.58728 -85.97513 590484.2 4160518
2    PAT   A1           2 37.58736 -85.97512 590484.5 4160527
3    PAT   A1           3 37.58741 -85.97512 590485.0 4160532
4    PAT   A1           4 37.58750 -85.97510 590486.4 4160543
5    PAT   A1           5 37.58759 -85.97510 590486.7 4160553
6    PAT   A1           6 37.58764 -85.97510 590486.1 4160559
7    PAT   A1           7 37.58777 -85.97509 590486.8 4160572
8    PAT   A1           8 37.58732 -85.97509 590487.4 4160522
9    PAT   A1           9 37.58738 -85.97507 590489.0 4160530
10   PAT   A1          10 37.58747 -85.97506 590490.4 4160539
```

From that I used this code to get the averges of the X and Y coordinates because I had multiple for one location

```
>  #Organizing and averaging multiple points into one
>     dat2<- dat %>% mutate(GridLet = str_extract(string = Grid, pattern = 'A|B|C')) %>%
>         group_by(GridLet, Site, Trap.Number) %>%
>         summarise(newx = mean(x), newy = mean(y))
>     head(dat2)
```

Then I had a data frame that looked like this

```
 GridLet Site  Trap.Number    newx     newy   
   <chr>   <chr>       <int>   <dbl>    <dbl> 
 2 A       Bla             2 594494. 4162282.  
 3 A       Bla             3 594501. 4162290. 
 4 A       Bla             4 594507. 4162298.  
 5 A       Bla             5 594513. 4162305.  
 6 A       Bla             6 594519. 4162312. 
 7 A       Bla             7 594525. 4162320.  
 8 A       Bla             8 594494. 4162275.  
 9 A       Bla             9 594501. 4162282. 
10 A       Bla            10 594507. 4162290.
```

From this, I want to combined Site, GridLet, and Trap.number so they are one column. To do that I have tried these three codes

```
#combinding site, grid, and trap number into one detector name
dat2$comb = paste0(dat2$Site, dat2$GridLet, dat2$Trap.Number) 
dat2$comb = paste(dat2$Site, dat2$GridLet, dat2$Trap.Number)
dat2$comb = str_c(dat2$Site, dat2$GridLet, dat2$Trap.Number)
```

Which all work! However, ultimately I want to create a data frame then just with the combination of those three columns and X and Y. I have been trying this code

```
 #creating data frame with only dector name and X and Y coordinates 
dat3<-select(dat2, comb, newx, newy, -GridLet, -Site)
```

But every time it adds back in GridLet and Site with a statement that says

> Adding missing grouping variables: `GridLet`, `Site

I am stumped on how to not include those in the next data frame to create something like this

```
   newx     newy comb  
   <dbl>    <dbl> <chr> 
 594488. 4162274. BlaA1 
 594494. 4162282. BlaA2 
 594501. 4162290. BlaA3 
 594507. 4162298. BlaA4 
 594513. 4162305. BlaA5 
 594519. 4162312. BlaA6 
 594525. 4162320. BlaA7 
 594494. 4162275. BlaA8 
 594501. 4162282. BlaA9 
 594507. 4162290. BlaA10
```

But preferably in the order of comb, newx, newy. Pleae I am open to any suggestions. Thank you in advance

Comment: `ungroup()` your data before the select.

Comment: what about just not using the two gridlet and site variables?
dat3<-select(dat2, comb, newx, newy)
sometimes it helps to specify dplyr select like this?
 dat3<-dplyr::select(dat2, comb, newx, newy)

Comment: @MrFlick using the ungroup function worked! thank you for your help!